# Python For loop repeating endlessly

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm currently writing a program to check speeds of cars and their license plates, and I want to repeat the function that does this x number of times, the problem I'm having though is that the function is repeating endlessly and is not adhering to the number of times I want it to loop. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
    if correctMatch:
    pass
else:
    with open('Camera Output.txt', 'a') as f:
        print("DATA RECORDED TO: Camera Output.txt")
        exactTime2 = datetime.now()
        f.write("{} has a non-standard license plate and has been recorded at {}.".format(licensePlate,
                                                                                              exactTime2) + "\n")
        f.write("---------------------------------------------------------\n")
if speedCarMph > 60:
    with open('Camera Output.txt', 'a') as f:
        print("DATA RECORDED TO: Camera Output.txt")
        exactTime= datetime.now()
        f.write("{} was travelling at {}MPH, recorded at {} and has broken the law.".format(licensePlate,
                                                                                                speedCarMph, exactTime) + "\n")
        f.write("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
licensePlateCheck()
for x in range(N):
    repeatNum = 0
    while repeatNum < 10:
        repeatNum += 1
        licensePlateCheck()
    if repeatNum == 10:
        print("Completed generation")
```

I also attempted to use a thread but that didn't work. If you need any more of the code, just ask.
The full code is here (excluding an unrelated function and the function choice):

```
import re
import threading
from queue import Queue
def licensePlateCheck():
   camInput1 = datetime.now()
   print(camInput1)
   print("Car is travelling...")
   time.sleep(0.1)
   print("Car has passed cam2")
   camInput2 = timedelta(seconds = random.uniform(5, 10))
   distance = 200
   duration = camInput2.total_seconds()
   print("Time Delta is equal to: {0}".format(duration))
   speedCarMs = distance/duration
   print("Car is travelling in m/s at: {0}".format(speedCarMs))
   speedCarMph = 2.237*speedCarMs
   print("Car is travelling in MPH at: {0}".format(speedCarMph))
   licenseCharNum = randint(2,9)
   licensePlate = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(licenseCharNum))
   licensePlateLayout = re.compile('[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]')
   correctMatch = licensePlateLayout.match(licensePlate)
   if correctMatch:
      pass
   else:
      with open('Camera Output.txt', 'a') as f:
         print("DATA RECORDED TO: Camera Output.txt")
         exactTime2 = datetime.now()
         f.write("{} has a non-standard license plate and has been recorded at {}.".format(licensePlate,
                                                                               exactTime2) + "\n")
        f.write("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
   if speedCarMph > 60:
      with open('Camera Output.txt', 'a') as f:
         print("DATA RECORDED TO: Camera Output.txt")
         exactTime= datetime.now()
         f.write("{} was travelling at {}MPH, recorded at {} and has broken the law.".format(licensePlate,
                                                                                                speedCarMph, exactTime) + "\n")
        f.write("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
   licensePlateCheck()
   for x in range(N):
      repeatNum = 0
      while repeatNum < 10:
         repeatNum += 1
         licensePlateCheck()
      if repeatNum == 10:
         print("Completed generation")
```

Comment: I can't quite see the purpose of using a `for` loop *and* a `while` loop. Could you explain why you have used two loops instead of one? What is the 'N' in `for x in range(N)`?

Comment: According to your code you want to trigger licensePlateCheck method 1 + x * 10 times?

Comment: I'd simply like to make a function repeat x number of times. N would represent the number of times that it would repeat, but I was confused, hence my coming here to help.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you have unnecessary used while loop:)

```
for x in range(N): // will iterate x times
    licensePlateCheck()

print("Completed generation")
```

With nested while loop, your method would execute:

x * 10 times:

- x - for loop
- 10 - while loop

Both For and While are correct, the choice is up to you.